# How to structure Rails link so that clicking it will update an ActiveRecord attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models in question, a Property model and an Application model.  The application has_many properties, and the properties belongs_to application.  As such, the Property model has an "application_id" field, which indicates the Application that is associated with the property.

I'd like to show a list of all possible Applications on the Property show page, with a link on the Application that, if clicked, will simply update application_id in the Property model to the ID of that application.

Here's my relevant code:

**views/properties/show.html.erb**

```
Choose an application template:
<ol class="microposts">
<% @owner.application.each do |template| %>
    <li><%= link_to "Application #{template.id}", :controller => "properties", :action => "update", :method => :put, :application_id  => template.id %></li>
<% end %>
</ol>
```

**Edit - adding relevant property controller code**

```
def show    
    @property=Property.find(params[:id])
    @owner=User.find(Property.find(params[:id]).user_id)
end

def update
    @property=Property.find(params[:id])
    if @property.update_attributes(property_params)
        flash[:success] = "Application added"
        redirect_to @property #going to change these redirects; this is just to get it working for now
    else
        redirect_to @property
    end
end

private

def property_params
    params.require(:property).permit(:address, :zip_code, :application_template_id)
end
```

This isn't working, though.  Can somebody assist me with how I might tweak the link_to code so that it will do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Also post your controller code.

Comment: @GhostRider - I posted the show actions on my property controller, as that's the view I'm working with here.  Is the problem that I haven't defined anything in my update action yet?  I was thinking that by explicitly referencing the update action in the link_to tag, I wouldn't need to add it in here.  Maybe that was wrong though

Comment: You do need to write an update action

Comment: you need to receive property id and application id in update action from view and then search the relevant property and update that object with application_id.

Comment: you can use button_to to display application object, it acts as a form and can submit the object. Add a hidden field with property_id to be submitted along with the form.

Comment: @GhostRider - is there any way you could help me out putting together that code in the update action?  Conceptually I understand what you're saying, but I'm just having trouble putting it into code that does the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question!

You'll want to do something like this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :properties do
   patch ("update_app/:application_id") #-> domain.com/properties/2/update_app/4
end
```

This will allow you to call:

```
#app/views/properties/show.html.erb
<%= link_to "Update", property_update_app_path(application_id), method: :patch %>
```

--

If you use the above link, you'll be able to use a controller as follows:

```
#app/controllers/properties_controller.rb
Class PropertiesController < ApplicationController
   def update_app
      @property = Property.find params[:id]
      @property.update({application_id: params[:app_id]})
   end
end
```